# Ready to use CSS Template or Framework

Tags: html, css, forms, css-tables

Do you know a source for pure CSS Templates? After setting up a simple Web Project I always wish to have a CSS file to:

- Set reasonable font settings for paragraphs and headers
- Polish my anchor tags
- Style my forms (if I have to touch the HTML for this one - no problem)
- Style my tables (I use headers and footers etc) using even & odd
- Maybe give me some handy classes for error boxes, etc.

So if I Google for a such CSS file I find CSS Homepage Templates with HTML Structure and massive CSS which I can't use without changing much. I find CSS examples for perfect tables, other examples for perfect forms but what I don't find is a single CSS File which when loaded in a properly formatted HTML website will make it look "okay" instead of the pure HTML look.

Do you get me?
Does anybody have a hint for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) might interested you but I believe it has a bit of javascript in it as well.

*Edit: As mentioned in comment you can use many of the Bootstrap features without using any javascript.*

Comment: Twitter Boostrap doesn't use Javascript for basic layout. It's only used for more advanced "components" and "Javascript Plugins".

Comment: After applying the CSS i had to give my tables the class tables. And apply some changes to the layout of my form. Bootstrap was a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps try the CSS off of [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html). Provides all sorts of consistent styling that's simple but elegant, in addition to some fancier element behaviors.

**Update:**

Adding to Yonix's related list, the following are alternative CSS preprocessors, which makes working with CSS a little more digestible:

- [Compass](http://compass-style.org/)
- [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/)

There's a bit of a learning curve when teaching yourself CSS, but some basic CSS is easier than you think.

Answer (score 4):

I've personally used bootstrap and I love it. I've also bookmarked few others to play with when bandwidth permits.

- [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)
- [Blueprint](http://blueprintcss.org/)
- [960 Grid](http://960.gs/)

**Update**: On related matter, I would also checkout CSS Preprocessors such as [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) that could help in writing better CSS and build up a custom library to use across projects.

Answer (score 2):

For quick prototyping/wireframing and pre-made HTML templates, I use [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com), as compared to Twitter Bootstrap. My advice is to familiarize yourself with their online documentation and delve into the main CSS file (foundation.css). You can build on top of that CSS file with the provided app.css file.

It comes with a lot of pre-made styles (buttons, forms, etc) and everything is responsive (fits on any size screen). You can choose to include all the plugins, or just the HTML and CSS. It also has an option to download the HTML templates, which come with a variety a layouts, such as a blog or a basic structure. I absolutely love it!